# Change the begining of String value in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, replace

In my table `TABLE1` there is a column `product` which is `VARCHAR` where all the values begin with character `1` e.g. `10003A`, `10004V` etc...

I want to update this column and replace the first character of each record, which is `1` with the character `2`. So the new values to be `20003A`, `20004V` etc... I tried:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET product = replace( product , '1', '2' ) WHERE product LIKE '1%';
```

but nothing happens.
Table is like:

```
    product         name           ...
"100036001000","description 1", more columns...
"100037001000","description 2", more columns...
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec878)

Comment: This query should work (but replaces all `1`s anywhere in the value). Does a SELECT work? Show some example data.

Comment: I haven't thought of this.. But in my case none records are modified... Which Select you mean?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE product LIKE '1%';`

Comment: Yes it returns all the records

Comment: Works for me. Please create an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: I added in the question.. Is it right?

Comment: Add something to the start of the string that you know won't be in the actual string, then do a replace including that, ie. `REPLACE(REPLACE('x' || product, 'x1', '2'), 'x', '')`

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ec878/2). The problem is not in any code that you have shown.

Comment: @CL That does replace the second "1", too. I think OP does not want that.